# how to make video autoplay when page loads bydefault?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, reactjs

How to make that video to be played automatically when the page load?
can you say how to play multiple videos which can be switched using other elements like buttons.
here's the source

```
`https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/BjbKrV`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can autoplay videos by adding the `autoplay` attribute to your video element.

For example:

```
<video controls autoplay>
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This code also includes the source you mentioned (it's from W3Schools).

This code may not work since Google Chrome and Safari sometimes block it.

Try this if the code doesn't work:

```
<video autoplay muted>
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" 
type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This will mute the video but it will work for sure.

Comment: I know that how to autoplay,
But I want to know how that to be done to the linked template which I gave :)